# Hi I am trying to run rails db:create in WSL Ubuntu and keep getting this error in regards to postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is my first time trying to set up postgres with rails and have tried so many different ways to get this working. Please help!

Error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'backend_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

When I run psql i receive this error again:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PostgreSQL installed properly? 
To check the version 
`$ postgres --version` .
If it's not installed on your system run
`$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`

If you have it installed login with

`$sudo su - postgres`

Then create a new user after logged in

`$ createuser --pwprompt username`

now create the database

`$ createdb -O username database_name` .